# Handle multiple login page for different type of user in asp.net core mvc 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In asp.net core i need to manage two different types of user (administrator and normal user).

When user session is expired i want administrater to be redirected to **baseurl/admistrator/login**  and for normal user redirect to **baseurl/login**

```
   services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(op =>
                {
                    op.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                    op.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                    op.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;

//here how can i set multiple login path
                    //op.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/administrator/account/login");
                    //op.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/login");
```

Does anyone have idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't know if a user is admin or not if the session is expired. The user has to login first. So why not use baseurl/login for all (anonymous) users and redirect to baseurl/administrator in case user is admin? An advantage is that you can secure the baseurl/administrator root for admins only.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to make login of administrator and normal user in same browser at a same time ??